# Set Column default value to NULL

Tags: python, mysql, null, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a `MySQL` table as follows:

```
create table USER
(
   USERID               int not null auto_increment,
   USERAVATAR           varchar(1024) default NULL,
   primary key (USERID)
);
```

I have created an entry in the table where `USERID = 1` and `USERAVATAR = NULL`.

In **Main.py**

```
user_list = session.query(USER).all()   
return jsonify(users=[r.serialize() for r in user_list])
```

**sqltables.py**

```
class USER(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'USER'

    USERID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    USERAVATAR = Column(String(1024))

    def serialize(self):  
        return unicode({           
        'id': self.USERID,        
        'userAvatar': self.USERAVATAR 
        })
```

The issue is that even though `USERAVATAR` has been set to `NULL` in the database, I'm getting `None` as my `JSON output.

```
{
  "users": [
    "{'userAvatar': None, 'id': 1}"
  ]
}
```

Would anyone know what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `serialize` function is casting into a string. Is that what you want in your JSON output, an array of strings instead of an array of objects?

If not, change your `serialize` function to not use `unicode()`